# Error (failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR occurs randomly only in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jetty, http2

my server on jetty serves API.
Some requests return 200, but other requests to the same endpoint with different params return:

`(failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

It occurs only in Chrome. In FF it works well.

Do you know what could be the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Jetty server DEBUG logs for more information, or report them here for analysis.

One reason for these errors may be the fact that Jetty protects against [these vulnerabilities](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/605641/) using parameter `jetty.http2.rateControl.maxEventsPerSecond` which defaults at 20.

Different browsers send different frames to the server; in particular, Chrome sends many `PRIORITY` frames to the server and for pages with a large number of resources, the `maxEventsPerSecond=20` threshold may be tripped.

You may want to configure this parameter to a higher value, say `50`, and see if the error still happens.

If you are using Jetty embedded, you want to use code similar to this:

```java
HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory http2 = ...;
http2.setRateControlFactory(endPoint -> new WindowRateControl.Factory(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, I also thought it is only in Chrome - when I tried FF for couple of times, it seemed to work. But few more couple of times revealed that in FF is just same random as in Chrome.

There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911570/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-http2-protocol-error-for-react-app-after-upg).

You might want to check if your Windows Update didn't pull KB5003637 which is suspected to cause this issue. My teammate did uninstall that patch and it fixed for him.