# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in our React app with .Net core 3.1

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, .net-core

I am facing following error in our React with .NET core 3.1 application. Our application was working perfectly until yesterday. Today my system auto rebooted post windows auto updates after that my application stopped working.

The home page is blank and the following error in chrome and Edge browser.

```
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
```

Comment: Even the default React template app is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Visual studio to Version 16.9.7 fixed the issue for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release

Answer (score 0):

See some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911570/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-http2-protocol-error-for-react-app-after-upg), they mention that the root cause is KB5003637 windows update installed. It also happens in my case: two days ago the app started to have errors like yours.

One of solutions is to uninstall the patch until MS releases a second patch.

Answer (score 0):

I can add that I'm getting the same error in Blazor.  I thought it was just a VS thing, but my live website is also failing randomly (about 1 time in 20).  So it looks a lot like a Windows problem.