# Angular project cannot get by client net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Tags: angular-cli

This problem occurred spontaneously without any changes to the code.
I run this app on localhost.

[image]

[[image]]2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see some discussion on similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911570/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-http2-protocol-error-for-react-app-after-upg).

Ther are couple different solutions, but what worked for me, was replacing all requests for css and js, to use http rather than default https:

So for example, this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/site.css">
```

instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css">
```