# My Asynchronous Controller throwing intermittent error and I can't pinpoint why it's happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an async controller that returns results from a collection.

Sometimes, I will get an intermittent error if I click around the page to fast.

The errors are (in the browser console):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Or it will return this error from the front-end:

```
500 : Ajax request has failed
```

I have tried debugging locally in Visual Studio and stepping through the code, but locally, I don't get any errors and I can't figure out why it's doing it.

I have added a line that checks to make sure the returned collection is not null, so it's not that.

Here is the controller:

```
[HttpGet("factapi/Factory/{factoryId}/engines")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Int32 factoryId)
{
    using (var tran = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var engineId = page.Assembly.Id.TrimToNull();
        if (engineId == null) return NoContent();
        var engines = await GetEngines(new Guid(engineId));
        if (engines == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok(engines);
    }
}
```

This is the async method that gets the engines:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Engine>> GetEngines(Guid id)
    {
        var engines = new List<Engine>();

        engines = await GetEngineList<Engine>(id);

        return engines.Where(t => start.LiesBetween(t.BuildTime.AddMinutes( - 7), t.BuildTime.AddMinutes((t.TimeBreak / 60) + 7)));

    }
```

And here is GetEngineList:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetEngineList<T>(Guid id)
{
    List<T> collectionVal = default(List<T>);

    var factoryResponse = await GetList(id);
    var fullList = factoryResponse.Results;
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
        };
        
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fullList);

    var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json, settings);
    collectionVal = final;
    return collectionVal;
}
```

Another set of eyes would be welcome! :)

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about) post can help you

Comment: @GuyKorol thanks but I couldn't find anything in my code or setup that hinted at any of those answers.

Comment: Which webserver you use?  And can  Iunderstand that the local vs2019 is running normally, and there will be errors after deployment. right?

Comment: @JasonPan I m using IIS on Windows Server 2016. Local is fine, but I run into intermittent errors on the IIS server.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Hi, I'm afraid there's some configuration we missed led this issue as you said it's all right in local. So you could you pls offer your iis version and maybe some error code not limited to 500. As I found some cases which is similar such as [this one](https://forums.iis.net/t/1214731.aspx). I mean we may change a way to troubleshot it.

Comment: What is `page.Assembly.Id` and why is factoryId never used?

Comment: Is KB5004476 on your server? Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911570/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-http2-protocol-error-for-react-app-after-upg) to see if it helps.